# EditText width is longer compared to above EditText

Tags: android

I have a activity which contains one AutoCompleteTextView and one EditText. The edittext is disabled via the xml file but the width is longer compared to the AutoCompleteTextView which is not disabled.why? and how can i have it the same size.here is the xml code for the second edittext.please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip"
android:gravity="right"> 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cusNameTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/customerName"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/cusName_CB"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cusaddrTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/cusaddress"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip" 
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_cusAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:state_enabled="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can see only one EditText here..

Comment: my apologies,i have edited my comment

Comment: one point to be noted is that when i remove the `android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" 
` the width becomes equal to the above widget

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/main"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/host_label"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/home"
         android:paddingTop="0dp"
         android:paddingLeft="15dp"
         android:textSize="25sp"
         android:textColor="#a5d4e2"
        android:text="host"
         android:textStyle="normal"
        />
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/port_label"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/home"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/host_input"
     android:paddingTop="0dp"
     android:textSize="25sp"
     android:textColor="#a5d4e2"
     android:text="port"
     android:textStyle="normal"  />

    <EditText 
          android:id="@+id/host_input" 
          android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
         android:layout_width="172dp" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
         android:layout_below="@id/host_label"
         android:layout_marginTop="4dp" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" 
         android:layout_marginRight="15dp"  />

      <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/port_input" 
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="100dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_below="@id/host_label"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/host_input"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/host_input"
       android:paddingTop="15dp"
       android:paddingLeft="15dp"
       android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#a5d4e2"
       android:text="username"
       android:textStyle="normal"/>

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/username_input" 
           android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
           android:layout_below="@id/username_label"
           android:layout_marginTop="4dp" 
           android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" 
          android:layout_marginRight="15dp" 
   />
```

Comment: i dont want to edit my UI design.can you please help me on my present design.i shall appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

According to your XML, the `EditText` background was gray color and no border was there.But the `AutoCompleteTextView` has no background color. So you have Border line for the `AutoCompleteTextView`. This makes you to look the `AutoCompleteTextView` bigger than the `EditText`.

I have given background color for both the views ,now it looks same.

The Border line only confused you.

The comparison is given below:

layout of your XML is [image]

the edited layout is [image]

Comment: no infact,it is the other way around.the edittext looks lonnger then the autocomplete widget. i think it has got to do with that background color. Is it an image i.e @android:color/darker_gray.by the way i dont see the darker_grey in the android-color folder.am i missing something

Comment: you are correct what you mentioned when viewing the UI on the emu. But on the samsung GT I8150. i get that issue. how can i upload a screenshot of the UI,so you can get a better idea on the issue